# Laravel Nova custom tool creation: vue component not refreshing

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js

I'm using Laravel Nova v1.1.4 within docker container.

I created a new tool via nova:tool command. Everything seems to be ok but everytime I update my vue component (tool.vue) the application does not display the updated data.
I run "npm run dev" from within /nova-components/myComponent/ directory, compiling is working fine but the application does not get updated.

My webpack.mix.js is the following:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix')
mix.setPublicPath('dist')
.js('resources/js/tool.js', 'js')
.sass('resources/sass/tool.scss', 'css')
```

I think is a "refresh" problem, in fact after "npm run dev" execution if I stop and restart the docker containres and refresh the web page then it displays the updated information I included in the vue componenet of the custom tool.

Do yuo have any idea to avoid containers stop/start?

Any help will be great.

Thanks,
MaxdB71

Answer (score 1):

You need to either disabled your cache in Chrome(or your browser of choice):

[image]

Or you need to implement versioning:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

If you have not done implemented one of these solutions you will simply get served the same file over and over until your cache expires.